# Who pays taxes if a minor sells an item on eBay using a parent's account?

Tags: united-states, taxes, selling, ebay

If a minor sells his/her computer at a gain on eBay using a parent's account (with the parent's permission), who pays taxes on the sale price?

I (16 years old) bought a cheap computer for about $20 with my own money a few months ago. I never used it, and identical computers are selling on eBay for about $60 due to the chip shortage. If I sell mine on eBay using my dad's account, the money goes into my parents' bank account, and they write me a check for the price it sold for, who pays taxes?

Comment: Did the minor sell the computer at a gain? Usually computers lose value pretty rapidly.

Comment: @littleadv it was never used and has increased in value significantly due to the chip shortage.

Comment: Well... If it is a minor's computer - then minor pays?

Comment: That's what I would expect, but it is a parent's account.

Comment: And that matters how?

Comment: I'm not sure; that's why I asked here. The money will go into my parents' bank account, then be transferred to mine, and I didn't know if it going through their account would mean they have to pay taxes.

Comment: So maybe describe the whole context if you want a useful answer? :) They may end up being intermediaries, and with large enough amounts there may be reporting requirements, but in the end - it's your gain, so it's your tax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, since the property is yours - so is the tax liability.

Since you're a minor there are some quirks to how taxation works. You can learn more about the "Kiddie Tax" reading through the [IRS Tax Topic 553](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc553) and the [IRS Publication 929](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p929).

In this case, you're talking about $40 capital gain here. If that's the only gain you have for the entire year then it is well below minimum income threshold at which a tax return is required ($1100 for unearned income for a dependent, see the [IRS Pub. 929](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p929#en_US_2021_publink1000203743)).

Comment: I will have to file taxes because I have over $600 in self employment income from another source.

Comment: @Someone how much more? See here for more specific instructions: https://www.irs.gov/publications/p929#en_US_2021_publink1000203747

Comment: It looks like the kiddie tax does not apply, because my income is under $2200.

Comment: At least $900, likely more.

Comment: Then you just add it to your tax return as a capital gain income

Comment: Okay, I'll do that, thank you!